# Intuition behind topological conjugacy between the flows of two systems of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

My book defines topological conjugacy between the flows of two differential equations as follows:

> Suppose $X' = AX \text{ and } X' = BX$ have flows $\phi ^A$ and $\phi ^B$. These two systems are topologically conjugate if there exists a homeomorphism $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfies $\phi ^B (t, h(X_0))= h(\phi ^A (t,X_0))$.

I understand the idea behind homemorphism, but why is conjugacy defined the way it is? Why is $h$ of the initial condition taken on one side while h of the flow is taken on the other? Why isn't it defined like $\phi ^B (t, X_0)= h(\phi ^A (t,X_0))$ instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind it is that: **the image of the orbit is the orbit of the image**, with corresponding times. And for that you need to have precisely $$\phi^B (t, h(X_0))= h(\phi ^A (t,X_0)).$$
More precisely, an orbit is $$\mathcal O^A(X_0)=\{\phi ^A (t,X_0):t\in\mathbb R\}.$$ Its image is thus $$h(\mathcal O^A(X_0))=\{h(\phi^A (t,X_0)):t\in\mathbb R\}=\{\phi^B (t,h(X_0)):t\in\mathbb R\}=\mathcal O^B(h(X_0)).$$ Summing up, the image of the orbit is the orbit of the image: $h(\mathcal O^A(X_0))=\mathcal O^B(h(X_0))$.

> Incidentally: Do you realize that with your proposed definition (in your last line), taking $t=0$ would give $h(X_0)=X_0$ for all $X_0$ and so $h$ would need to be the identity map?

Comment: No, I didn't realize that my definition would lead to that. Thanks for pointing it out. Could you elaborate a bit on " the image of the orbit is the orbit of the image"?

Comment: @cppcoder Edited.

Comment: I think I get it now, thanks for making it clearer.

Comment: @JohnB How do you show that if A and B are equivalent then they are topologically conjugated?